# Removing cushion from Aldi Bikemate Boodie seat

Tags: child-seat

I would like to remove the cushion from my Aldi Bikemate Boodie seat - it is unpleasant after spending the winter in a damp shed. There is only so much cleaning I can do while it's on and I don't want to expose the plastic shell to cleaning chemicals.

(Edit: Daniel R Hicks pointed out it looks like "Polisport Bubbly Maxi" and it is exactly the same seat, and it turns out so is "Raleigh Avenir" and others - they even keep the "boodie" embossed on the cushion. Clearly it's all licensing etc.)

I contacted Teknihall using the info on the product information plate - but I'm not sure if Teknihall are the original licensor or one of the many licensees. Anyway, they said they would look into this, they may still get back to me and I will update this question if they do.

The problem is that the cushion is held in place by a clamp/jaw which I highlighted in photos 5 and 10. It seems like it should be possible to slip the jaw off. I gave it a go and it didn't move. I'm conscious I will brake/strain the "tongue" that the buckle sits on if put any more force on it. I can see how there might an element of rotation involved in slipping it on and off. I can't see any catches/levers I would need to prize/lift.

**The question is: has anyone removed the cushion on a seat like mine or similar?** The tongue that holds the buckle is clearly a safety critical part so I don't want to mess with it unless I am happy my actions are safe.

0 Manufacturer's photo taken [from Aldi's website](https://www.aldi.co.uk/bikemate-children%27s-bike-seat/p/084211212901300) - NB this photo was added after several people commented the photos are not clear.
[image: manufacturer's photo]
1 top general view
[image: 1 top general view]
2 top showing back of buckle
[image: 2 top showing back of buckle]
3 top showing front of buckle
[image: 3 top showing front of buckle]
4 clamp top close up
[image: 4 clamp top close up]
5 clamp top close up annotated
[image: 5 clamp top close up annotated]
6 bottom general view
[image: 6 bottom general view]
7 bottom seen from prong ends
[image: 7 bottom seen from prong ends]
8 bottom looking vertically up
[image: 8 bottom looking vertically up]
9 cushion clamp - bottom view
[image: 9 cushion clamp - bottom view]
10 cushion clamp - bottom view - annotated
[image: 10 cushion clamp - bottom view - annotated]
11 product information plate
[image: 11 product information plate]

Comment: NAA - but you might get some cleaning results out of a spray-on like a couch or automotive-interior cleaner, or simply flood the whole cushion with warm water and dishwash, massage, repeat, rinse till soaps out, squeegee and let it air dry.

Comment: It looks to me like the tongue might be designed to catch and not release. You may be able to lever it up a little and free something up, rather than directly forcing a part.  Unfortunately despite your best efforts black-on-black never photographs well and this sort of thing isn't very clear in photos anyway

Comment: I'm not sure why this has attracted a downvote with no explanation: it's clearly on topic and the OP has done a good job of explaining the problem

Comment: Yeah, as Criggie suggests, you should be able to able to hose down the entire seat.  (Then set the thing out in the sun for several hours to dry, if there is such a thing (that alien-looking bright thing in the sky) where you live.)

Answer (score 4):

posting an update to this as I’ve just found myself asking the same question.

Use a flat head screwdriver to lift each end of the clip holding the loop at the bottom of the seat cushion (highlighted in pic #5 in OP’s post). It will pop out quite easily allowing the loop of fabric to be removed. To reattach, simply press the clip back into place - it makes a reassuring click!

Comment: Lovely. Can you confirm that the buckle remains securely attached throughout the process? In other words, can you do this without interfering with the buckle? And do you by any chance have any photos?

Answer (score 1):

First, for what it's worth, this is probably a Polisport brand seat, possibly the "Bubbly Maxi" style.  Contacting Polisport (however one might do that) would be more likely to be productive than talking to Aldi.

Unfortunately, I can't make much sense of the pictures.

Comment: Thanks. I added a photo of the product information plate which has some pretty detailed information and no mention of Polisport. Then I googled "Polisport Bubbly Maxi" and it is exactly the same seat, as is "Raleigh Avenir" and other - they even keep the "boodie" embossed on the cushion. Clearly it's all licensing etc. I contacted Teknihall (as opposed to Aldi) using the info on the plate - but I'm not sure if Teknihall are the original licensor or one of the many licensees.

Comment: @pateksan Teknihall is a company that provides product support. Companies pay them to answer email and phone calls to support products like this seat. Theoretically, they will be able to talk to the maker/distributor of the seat and get back to you with information. Monz is the distributor of the seat https://www.monz-international.de/index.php/en/ I didn't find any manuals on their site.